# PreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when having comment and parameter within sql-string

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to get ParameterMetaData from an java.sql.PreparedStatement object.

While documentation says its throwing an SQLException when something goes wrong on the database, I currently am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I am using this JDBC driver URL:
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
I have an ojdbc6.jar and a 64bit JDK 1.6.0.45 in use.

I am doing the following:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = myOracleConn.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatements.add(stmt);
ParameterMetaData bla2 = stmt.getParameterMetaData(); //this Line throws the Exception
```

I found out that this only happens, when I use a comment within the sql-String.

So, when my SQL is:

1) (no comment but parameter)

```
"SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = ?" --> no error occurs
```

2) (comment and parameter)

```
"/* mySampleComment */ SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = ?" --> the indexoutofbounds exception occurs
```

3) (comment but no parameter)

```
"/* mySampleComment */ SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 1" --> no error occurs
```

I wonder if thats it and I must not use comments within my sqls or whether I am missing something...
Does someone know something about this?

edit1:
Using --comments instead of /**/ results in the same behavior.
edit2:
it seems not at all, I have a big SQL which has included

```
\n\t\t\t\t--great
```

which gets the exception.
When including this into on of the sample sqls still postet, it will work

If I am missing some information, just request for it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you just found a bug in the Oracle JDBC driver. On the other hand, I don't think JBDC drivers are ready to receive Java comments inside the query...

Comment: Standard SQL doesn't support that kind of comments. Usually it only supports one-line comments that start with `--` (and then, of course, you can't put them at the beginning of the line). But why would you put comments in SQL strings rather than in the program that runs them?

Comment: and what aboute the use of hints? they are coded as comments, too

edit: i use comments in sql because sql is inputted from extern an the comments are describing the sql not the java routines

Comment: Thank you for editing your question, but the part in your "edit2" is not clear. What is "not at all" and there are some misspelled words after that that are hard to understand. Can you show what you added where, and what the result was?

Comment: Are you accessing the metadata before or after executing the statement?

Comment: Please provide the driver version and the stacktrace.

Comment: the indexoutofbounds exception occurs not due to the comments in the SQL statement but you have to set the value of the 1 e.g. ps.setString(1, "valueOfOne"); or ps.setInt(1, 5);

Comment: Post the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You're should set parameters to the statement before executing .getParameterMetaData()

```
PreparedStatement stmt = myOracleConn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1,"test"); 
ParameterMetaData metadata = stmt.getParameterMetaData();
```

Comment: It doesn't say so in the Javadoc. It does say 'For some queries and driver implementations, the data that would be returned by a `ParameterMetaData` object may not be available until the `PreparedStatement` has been executed', but that doesn't appear to apply here.

Comment: Well... try and report the results...